# App crashes when extending ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, android-appcompat, android-actionbaractivity

I have an error catch when I extend `ActionBarActivity`. If I extend `Activity` there is no errors.

The thing is in my other activities it works perfectly. At first, I thought it's was because my previous activity put extras in the intent. But even without it the app crash.

Here is my code :

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class FullscreenActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
    }
}
```

**EDIT :** and the result of logs :

```
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testlfm/com.example.testlfm.FullscreenActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:102)
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at com.example.testlfm.FullscreenActivity.onCreate(FullscreenActivity.java:36)
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
09-21 18:21:39.413: E/AndroidRuntime(26944):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Whats your error? Post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the error you have posted:  "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity." You should be using the appcompat library as a Library Project, in which case you'll see the available themes under res/values in that project

Comment: Can you be more specific ?

Comment: Find it ! Thank you, I add the Theme in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Yeah, but it force me to wait 3 minutes :)

Comment: To make sure the answer is clear for people coming in the future: How do you use the appcompat library as a Library Project?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.theredpill.myfirstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.theredpill.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.theredpill.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no assets folder in your project create a one under src/main. Copy your font file into the assets folder.

in your java file you can use like this
       //Font path
        String fontPath = "MyCustomFOnt.TTF";

```
    EditText txtCustom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editor1);
    // Loading Font Face
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);
    // Applying font
    txtCustom.setTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried whole bunch of things (themes, importing external appcompat jars etc).
The only one helped to me:
1) manually copy android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar to the lib folder of the project;
2) right click on the project -> Properties -> Libraries -> Add JARs (not external jars) - > select jars from the lib folder (which we copied on step 1) -> Order and Export tap -> Uncheck old support libraries and check new, which we just added. -> OK.