# Unable to run Android Project On Device and Emulator

Tags: android

```
04-28 10:52:09.745: E/AndroidRuntime(28536): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lociiapp/com.lociiapp.HomeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
04-28 10:52:09.745: E/AndroidRuntime(28536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
04-28 10:52:09.745: E/AndroidRuntime(28536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
04-28 10:52:09.745: E/AndroidRuntime(28536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
04-28 10:52:09.745: E/AndroidRuntime(28536):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
04-28 10:52:09.745: E/AndroidRuntime(28536):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
04-28 10:52:09.745: E/AndroidRuntime(28536):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
04-28 10:52:09.745: E/AndroidRuntime(28536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
04-28 10:52:09.745: E/AndroidRuntime(28536):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 10:52:09.745: E/AndroidRuntime(28536):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-28 10:52:09.745: E/AndroidRuntime(28536):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
04-28 10:52:09.745: E/AndroidRuntime(28536):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
04-28 10:52:09.745: E/AndroidRuntime(28536):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-28 10:52:09.745: E/AndroidRuntime(28536): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
04-28 10:52:09.745: E/AndroidRuntime(28536):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:111)
04-28 10:52:09.745: E/AndroidRuntime(28536):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
04-28 10:52:09.745: E/AndroidRuntime(28536):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
04-28 10:52:09.745: E/AndroidRuntime(28536):    at com.lociiapp.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:49)
04-28 10:52:09.745: E/AndroidRuntime(28536):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
04-28 10:52:09.745: E/AndroidRuntime(28536):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1150)
04-28 10:52:09.745: E/AndroidRuntime(28536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
04-28 10:52:09.745: E/AndroidRuntime(28536):    ... 11 more
```

This is My logcat Error and there is not Error in My Application even i have added appv7appcomact jar file But i am unable to run this Project on device or emulator Please help me where am Doing mistake .

Comment: What's `49` line in your 'HomeActivity'?

Comment: Home Activity is class which extend from ActionBarActivity

Comment: try this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933817/app-crashes-when-extending-actionbaractivity

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/pJQ8BAi5EDHLZ2h7r6nVfQ  this is my Manifiest.

Comment: shift this line from inside activity tag to application tag:  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending `ActionBarActivity` in your `MainActivity`, you will have to change the parent theme in `values-v11` also.
So the `style.xml` in values-v11 will be -

```
 <!-- res/values-v11/themes.xml -->
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
    <style name="QueryTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Any customizations for your app running on devices with Theme.Holo here -->
    </style>
 </resources>
```

in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity
        ...
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" />
```

Comment: i have applied following change But still Problem some new LogCat Error is coming http://paste.ofcode.org/utmVFt6JybJ4iqDSv8H8Ep  plz check

Comment: Did you define style.xml file ? If yes, You have to check for other folders, that contain styles files as well, that could possibly override your styles.

Comment: So we need to change in All Style.xml file?

Comment: Yes, you need to change in all style.xml

Comment: Still same issue while i have change in All style.xml file .

Comment: Please read this one will surely helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063395/actionbarcompat-java-lang-illegalstateexception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcom

Comment: Still Problem Not  Running on device and same Logcat Error .http://paste.ofcode.org/utmVFt6JybJ4iqDSv8H8Ep

Comment: plz tell me about this issue it was working in my Home Pc But i dont know here its not working while its .apk file work fine

Comment: Clean your project and try once.

Comment: can u please tell appcomact v7 .jar file which version came