# Unfortunately, 'app_name' has stopped

Tags: android

I´m new in android developer. I´m executing an application but it´s giving me the error: Unfortunatelly, 'app_name' has stopped

My code:

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
   private ListView lista;
   //array de datos
    private String[] datos = {"Item uno","Item dos","Item tres", "Item cuatro","Item cinco",
   "Item seis","Item siete","Item ocho","Item nueve","Item diez"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Referenciamos la lista a la actividad
        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
        //creamos el arrayadapter
        ArrayAdapter< String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, datos);
        //Vinculamos el adaptador a la lista
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The main layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.cursoandroid.miarrayadapter.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
    >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lista"
      />
```

The manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cursoandroid.miarrayadapter" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

    </FrameLayout>
```

[image]
[image]
My string xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">MiarrayAdapter</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

</resources>
```

Thank you. Could anyone say me, what´s wrong?

File logcat:

```
01-12 08:49:40.101    1253-1253/com.cursoandroid.miarrayadapter E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cursoandroid.miarrayadapter, PID: 1253
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cursoandroid.miarrayadapter/com.cursoandroid.miarrayadapter.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:151)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
            at com.cursoandroid.miarrayadapter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: could you show your strings.xml file?

Comment: Yes I edited my post. you can seing it now

Comment: can you post code under menu_main.xml

Comment: If there is no use of menu in your app you can comment these 2  method onCreateOptionsMenu() and onOptionsItemSelected() and run your app. Check is it still crashing

Comment: I comment these 2 method but I getting the same error

Comment: </FrameLayout> in your manifest file above.... is this just a copy/paste error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [App crashes when extending ActionBarActivity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933817/app-crashes-when-extending-actionbaractivity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When developing if you encounter any exception first look for this part "Caused by:" in the stack trace. It shows the exact reason for the failure.

In this case it clearly shows

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Then it's easy to debug to your self or ask the question more meaningfully. Just a suggestion as you are a new developer

Answer (score 0):

In your styles.xml file, use Appcompat theme :

```
<style name="**YourThemeName**" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

</style>
```

Now use this theme in your AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/**YourThemeName**">

.....

</application>
```

Comment: Don´t work putting in parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">, marked how red error

Answer (score 0):

u  r extending  `ActionBarActivity` which require `Theme.AppCompat`.

so replace `extends ActionBarActivity` by `extends Activity`

**OR**

do like this

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
```

for more info:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html