# error AppCompat you need use app.themecompat

Tags: android

referring to thread [Unfortunately, 'app_name' has stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897647/unfortunately-app-name-has-stopped), I solved it, I get a new error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cursoandroid.miarrayadapter, PID: 1253
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cursoandroid.miarrayadapter/com.cursoandroid.miarrayadapter.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread
```

Mi main Activity is already app.compat

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cursoandroid.miarrayadapter" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
        <activity
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But I´m geeting to execute the application:

[image]

I dont understand it?

Comment: Have you properly referenced library project?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the appcompat library the xmlns attribute in menu_main.xml should be:

`<menu xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  .... >`

as given in the android documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html